# Should I check parameter before using it in methods?

Tags: php, variables, methods

I'm going to build some public PHP packages, Following standards is a priority for me.

PHP lets users call methods even if they don't pass required parameters to it.

My question. Should I check parameter before using it in methods? (like following example)

```
public function setVariable($value)
{
    if(isset($value))
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Value must be an int value!");
    $this->variable = (int) $value;
}
```

Or just do my job!

```
public function setVariable($value)
{
    $this->variable = (int) $value;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: Your `empty($value)` check doesn't make sense. It will pass for anything that isn't empty (eg `Hello world`), but will fail for `0`, which is an int value. How about using `is_int()` instead?

Comment: "PHP lets users call methods even if they don't pass required parameters to it." - Not really, you get an E_WARNING!

Comment: In your first example, you've changed `empty($value)` to `isset()` and in doing so reversed the logic - this is definitely wrong in this context! As @Yannis suggests, for a _required parameter_ you only need to check `is_int()`. Or in your case `!is_int()`.

Comment: consider my question more generally. it's not exactly about int, if it was is I would ask in Stack-Overflow.

Comment: Yes, I realise this is just an example and `is_int()` was just following along with your example (and Yannis's comment) using integers; you could use `is_<anything>()` here. But I was really commenting on your change to `isset()` - this makes even less sense - in the general sense.

Comment: Are u agree with throwing Exception on getting wrong data type?

Comment: It depends. It depends what you are doing in your function and where the arguments are coming from. This is PHP - a "wrong" data type does not necessarily mean a wrong value. See [my comment to Yannis answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/286834/should-i-check-parameter-before-using-it-in-methods/286852#comment591690_286835). Take the "int" example... if it is wrong for your function to accept anything other than an _int_ ie. you cannot continue in a meaningful way if something other than an _int_ is passed then yes, throw an exception.

Comment: However, this is PHP, where type coercion is a "feature". If your function accepts arguments that "look like" integers (for example) that may be coming straight from a cookie, submitted (sanitized) form data, or some other serialized string data then _failing_ on a strict data type might not be the way to go.

Comment: I've removed the question about type hinting in php as that is a *completely* different question than the one asked here.  I also removed the opinion and request for discussion. Please read the [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and avoid asking questions that are calls for discussion (“I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”) or rants in disguise (“PHP sucks, do you agree?”)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm going to build some public  public PHP packages.

Public as in "Open Source", "public to the whole world"? Then do yourself a favor and do as much validation as you can as long as you do not suffer serious performance problems. Even when you provide some documentation saying "this function does not handle left out parameters", expect a lot of people <strike>completely ignoring your package's documentation</strike> not reading all the gory details of your documentation in full. And if a problem occurs, the error message should users give a clear description of what **they** did wrong, otherwise they will blame your package, might blame you, and send you dozens of support mails.

So I recommend not only to throw an exception, but to make your the error messages in those exceptions are as clear as possible.

Answer (score 2):

[As of PHP5, type hinting is a thing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). The most important distinctions are the following:

- You cannot type hint scalar/numerical, string, Resource, or Trait data.
- You can force parameters that are objects, arrays, or anonymous functions.
- You can type hint using interface names, class names, `object` keyword, `array` keyword, or `callable` keyword (for anonymous functions/callbacks).
- When a type hinted function or method is called with mismatched parameters, a catchable fatal error will occur (not an Exception).
- If you specify `null` as a default value, type hinting is somewhat useless.

I would suggest at least checking `isset` and `is_null` before running your algorithm, and I highly suggest further type checking with things like `is_string`, `is_int`, `is_float`, etc. Type casting is also valid. Edit: this only applies for when you cannot use type hinting for a function, e.g. scalar parameters.

Returning `false` or throwing an Exception are all context specific questions -- you have to determine which fits each particular function/algorithm in your package, which will include considering how someone using your code should interact with it. My favorite example of [contrived Exception throwing is Sentry](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#example). I mean, look at all of those catch blocks. Maybe you'll want your code to throw that many things to provide different information, or perhaps you can return a boolean, or perhaps you can throw a `new Exception("Message text")`. It's a personal choice for each piece of code. I recommend looking at potential applications where your package will be useful and see how well your package would integrate with those coding styles.

#### tl;dr version

The only primitives you can [type hint are `array` and `object`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). You can type cast or type check other primitives. Function/method calls with parameters that fail to satisfy type hints results in a catchable fatal error. What to do when parameters sent to your function/method are mismatched is a personal, context specific choice that nobody can definitively answer without seeing your code.

Edit: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724696/2103394

Comment: Why check "`isset` **and** `is_null`"?

Comment: For scalar variables or if there is some other reason to not use type hinting. I'll make that more clear.

Comment: you mean, we should use isset() before is_string (4example)?

Answer (score 0):

I try to follow the following:

For externally-called code, do as much explicit error handling as possible, to provide the best experience for the caller and highest level of protection for your own code against inbound data that might partially succeed in unintended ways.

For private calls, I'd explicitly handle bad data if it was possible for that data to somehow get through the call without failing violently on its own.  So, I guess I'd call this defensive trapping.

It seems to me that API writers should try to handle invalid data and provide great error messages on all external calls, both to help the user and to help yourself when you invariable have to support some production issue.